# How can I get pokemon information in pokehub coordinates in vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, pokemon-go

How can I get pokemon information in this website(https://pokehubcoordinates.com/pvp) in Vb.net?
I tried two ways. but it didn't work

1. code

   ```
     Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://pokehubcoordinates.com/pvp")
   ```
2. code

   ```
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://pokehubcoordinates.com/pvp")
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()        
            Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                    Dim html As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    File.WriteAllText("e:\test.html", html)
            End Using
    End Using
   ```

Comment: As all web pages that are generated by scripts, you cannot get the generated data using a WebRequest, you need something that can interpret the scripts and render a page, i.e., a compatible WebBrowser.

Comment: yes i use cefsharp.winform (chromium) but How can I get pokemon information?

Comment: When the HTML is generated, using standard methods as `GetElementsByTagName()`, `GetElementById()`, iterating the child elements, getting Attribute values, InnerHtml etc. or using a tool as [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and XPath expressions to returns the nodes you care about.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and report back. thank you

Comment: @Jimi
hi master;
 I tried this code. but not work. please help me. im amateur programmer. why did work?

        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://pokehubcoordinates.com/pvp")
        Dim values As JObject = JObject.Parse(result)
        Dim finalHTML As String = values.GetValue("col-lg-4 col-md-6 p-1")
        Dim doc = New HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(finalHTML)
        Dim pokes = doc.DocumentNode.Elements("div").Select(Function(o) o.InnerText.Trim())
        MsgBox(String.Join(",", pokes))

Comment: As already mentioned, you cannot use any form of WebRequest (the WebClient *internals* is still a WebRequest). You need a WebBrowser that renders the HTML, running the scripts it contains, then use the DOM of the WebBrowser's Document to call standard methods (`GetElementsByTagName()` & Co.) - if available - or get the rendered HTML document from the WebBrowser and pass it to a parser, as HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: i have chromium browser (cefsharp) . i see all pokemons in website in my program. but i dont know it. how i get all pokes? please give me example come?

Comment: Well, then get the HTML Document (when completed) from your WebBrowser and pass it to HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: thanks master 
i love u. =)

Comment: hi master @Jimi 
i need to help again. I change the selected one in the combobox but the pokemon do not change. this is the code i use
`_browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName('form-control col-3 col-sm-2')[1].selectedIndex = '1'; })();")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ShowSource()
    Dim ts As Task = getSource()
End Sub


Private Async Function getSource() As Task
    Dim source As String = Await _browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync()
    Dim dokuman As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    dokuman.LoadHtml(source)
    Dim veri1 As String = dokuman.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=""root""]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div")(0).InnerText
    textbox1.text =veri1 


End Function
```